# Remove all the empty lines from a file

Tags: php, file-io

I have the following script that is supposed to loop through the contents of a file and remove all the empty lines then rewrite the file only without the empty lines. Without writing to the file, or in otherwords by just having it echo the line, it works flawlessly. However when I try to get it to write to a file it just erases all the content of the file. No errors are returned. I'm open to new ways of the script running so anyway to achieve what I'm looking for would be great. Thanks in advance.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

$filenameindex = "somefile";
$filecont = file($filenameindex);
$fileindex = fopen($filenameindex, "w") or die("can't open file");
foreach($filecont as $line)
{
    if(strlen($line) > 0)
    {
        fwrite($fileindex,$line);    
    }
}  
fclose($fileindex);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not strictly a php solution, but if your only goal is to remove whitespace, how about just using UNIX `sed`?

```
sed -i '/^$/d' /somewhere/somefile.txt
```

You can call this from in PHP with `shell_exec()` or backticks.  This is also assuming that you're on a UNIX system, but it will remove the overhead of loading the file to PHP.

Comment: Sorry got caught up and forgot.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using preg_replace

```
$filename = "somefile.txt";
$str = file_get_contents($filename);
$str = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\r\n", $str);
file_put_contents($filename, $str);
```

Note!
For displaying the line breaks correctly in notepad, i used "\r\n" instead of just "\n"

Comment: that just moved all the content to the same line and put a period between where it moved it. I've tried to use preg_replace before but could never get it to work properly...

Comment: Oh sorry.. are you opening the file with notepad? If you are, you have to use "\r\n" for line breaks. 
So the preg_replace line should look like this:
$str = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\r\n", $str);